# Ubuntu can't read SD card after camera adds photos

Tags: mount, sd-card, camera

I have an SanDisk SD card it works very well on ubuntu, it reads/writes files as normal. But after I put the card in the camera and take some photos it doesn't work properly on ubuntu anymore and it is very slow. It doesn't mount automatically and I can't even view the images.

I tried formatting it several times on ubuntu and on the camera as well but as soon as I put it back in the camera and take photos the problem pops up again.

Comment: Maybe the size is 64 GB or more and the camera is creating an exFAT file system in the card (rather than a FAT32 file system). In that case Ubuntu needs extra software for it, so install the program packages `exfat-utils` and `exfat-fuse`.

Comment: I have the packages already , didn't help and the  card is 32 GB

Comment: How are you ejecting the card from the camera and ubuntu?

Comment: `sudo parted -l` and `mount` in both states might help, if you're command line literate. Are you? Check my profile  for hints on using `journalctl` to read system logs.

Comment: I tried everything nothing worked it seems that ubuntu can't mount SDHC cards so I have installed windows alongside Ubuntu .